# Empty ListView show another activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, textview

I am making an application which uses `ListView` to show DB elements. But in the first opening or when user will delete everything DB will be empty and then ListView will show blank screen. I want to show a message when it happens. Not only TextView but also `Button`. For example "DB now empty. Click on button and try to add some records". `ListView` 's `setEmptyView` method allows to add only `TextView` . Is it really possible to create a layout and show it when `ListView` is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the property setEmptyView.

If the list is empty and your desired display.

```
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst);
    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.empty_view, null);
    ((ViewGroup)listView.getParent()).addView(child);
    listView.setEmptyView(child);
```

Comment: works. but can i display an alternative layout instead of only text view?

Comment: Yes,You can use getLayoutInflater (). Inflate create a layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add a button in the activity layout if your list is empty.
Set onClickListner on the button and override the onClick().

Refer below code:

```
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setId("btnDynamic");
btn.setText("Go to create entry page");
linear.addView(btn, params);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                "Button clicked index = " + id_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    } 
});
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It works thank You. but it's not what i wanted. this way is not beautiful. I mean it's very static. I want to show a layout. With images and buttons on it. But this code really works.

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-define a layout containing text view and and button as you stated in your question and set it's visibility = gone in your xml or in java code. When the List View will be empty you can set visibility the visibility of the listview.setVisibility(View.GONE) and set your's layout (containing button and a textview) layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)